# Ruby API: Validation of virtual password field is not working with has_secure_password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is my model:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { equal_to: 6 }
end
```

My strong params in controller:

```rb
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password)
end
```

But when I make the request the api yields:

```rb
{
  "password": [
    "can't be blank",
    "can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

Two times. Why is that?

Comment: what is your request body?